# Is RAM the solution?

Tags: rendering, baking

I would like to ask a question, I hope I find a solution here.

I’m working with Blender for like a month already and I just started to notice that the baking and rendering process takes pretty long. Rendering would not be much of a problem (for now), but with baking I’d love to make things better.
As I understood, baking is about RAM. I have **16GB Corsair XMSE DDR3** (2x4gb + 2 – not sure, if they are 2x4 or 1+1) and a **Gigabyte GA-X79-UD3** Motherboard with **4 Channel Memory Architecture** (up to 96GB).
I was planing to buy 32GB DDR4, but before that I wanted to ask if it’s worth the buy and if so, what RAM should I purchase. 2x16 or 4x8 – what would make the best performace? Does this make a big difference for blender? Also, my GPU is a **Zotac GTX 760 (4GB)**, but I thought I replace that only later.

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Best
M

Comment: This question is more like https://blenderartists.org forums, go ask it there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about hardware recommendations

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to determine whether the bottleneck actually is the RAM.... This is dependent on operating system - if Windows you can use Resource Monitor to view how much is in use. On Linux you could use 'top' or System Monitor - either should give you what you need. The key is to see whether Blender is using up all of the 'free' memory - and causing swapping out to disk - you'll see the 'free' drop away to zero and disk activity drastically increase if that is the case. If you have free memory available while baking then the problem isn't the amount of RAM but elsewhere - so increasing the RAM won't give you any benefit in that area (but could still be useful elsewhere!)

Comment: Yep. For me, my (incredibly poor) GPU is the bottleneck.